# Populate custom tree with records from database

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, umbraco

I have recently started using Umbraco and am in the process of figuring out how to add my own custom sections into it.

So far I've managed to add a new section and I've also started adding a custom tree with the help of various blog posts such as: http://www.robertgray.net.au/2011/5/10/creating-a-custom-content-tree-in-umbraco and http://www.geckonewmedia.com/blog/2009/8/3/how-to-create-a-custom-section-in-umbraco-4

The purpose of this new section is to display enquiries that I would like to store in the database. The records just need to be viewed but not editable.

So far I have a root node called 'Enquiries' and a node below that called 'General Enquiries'. I would like to list all enquiries as child nodes of 'General Enquiries' and then when clicked on, I'd like to be able to display the enquiry details in the main area on the right.

In the first blog post linked to above, the following code has been provided to demonstrate how to display the child nodes:

```
using atomicf1.domain.Repositories;
using atomicf1.persistence;
using umbraco.cms.presentation.Trees;

namespace atomicf1.cms.presentation.Trees
{
    public class loadDrivers : BaseTree
    {
        private IDriverRepository _driverRepository;

        public loadDrivers(string application) : base(application)
        {
            _driverRepository = new DriverRepository();
        }

        protected override void CreateRootNode(ref XmlTreeNode rootNode)
        {
            rootNode.Icon = FolderIcon;
            rootNode.OpenIcon = FolderIconOpen;
            rootNode.NodeType = TreeAlias;
            rootNode.NodeID = "init";
        }

        public override void Render(ref XmlTree tree)
        {           
            var drivers = _driverRepository.GetAll();

            foreach(var driver in drivers) {
                var dNode = XmlTreeNode.Create(this);
                dNode.NodeID = driver.Id.ToString();
                dNode.Text = driver.Name;
                dNode.Icon = "user.png";
                dNode.Action = "javascript:openDrivers(" + driver.Id + ")";
                tree.Add(dNode);
            }            
        }

        public override void RenderJS(ref System.Text.StringBuilder Javascript)
        {
            Javascript.Append(
                @"
                    function openDrivers(id) 
                    {
                        parent.right.document.location.href = 'plugins/atomicf1/editDriver.aspx?id=' + id;
                    }
                ");
        }
    }
}
```

From what I can work out, it seems that the 'drivers' in this example are being drawn from `_driverRepository`. However, there doesn't appear to be any code examples explaining what that is and how that actually retrieves the data from the database in the first place.

Any help on this would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me preface this by saying I know very little about Umbraco so this is just based on observation!

If you look at the source code in the [github repository](https://github.com/robgray/f1speedguides) linked to on Robert Gray's blog post, you will find the implementation of [DriverRepository](https://github.com/robgray/f1speedguides/blob/master/src/atomicf1.persistence/DriverRepository.cs) (which is just a shell subclass of the underlying generic [AbstractRepository](https://github.com/robgray/f1speedguides/blob/master/src/atomicf1.persistence/AbstractRepository.cs) abstract base class where the real work happens). This code is nothing to do with Umbraco, it's just an implementation of the Repository Pattern in conjunction with [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/) for data access within the sample F1 application that is sitting on top of Umbraco in this case. What this code is doing is retrieving all the Drivers from the application, looping over them and creating corresponding XmlTreeNodes within Umbraco.

In your situation, you simply swap out references to (I)DriverRepository with whatever data access mechanism you are using in your application.

For example, if you were to take a similar (albeit simpler) approach to Robert, you might have something like the following in your application:

```
public class EnquiryRepository : IEnquiryRepository {

  // Methods for saving Enquiries, retrieving single Enquiries etc would go here...

  public IEnumerable<Enquiry> GetAll() {
    // Data access logic here - retrieve via NHibernate, Entity Framework,
    // ADO.net, in-memory objects (as below) etc.
    var enquiries = new List<Enquiry>
    {
      new Enquiry('Enquiry 1 title', 'Enquiry 1 content'),
      new Enquiry('Enquiry 2 title', 'Enquiry 2 content'),
      new Enquiry('Enquiry 3 title', 'Enquiry 3 content')
    }
    return enquiries;
  }

}
```

You would then work with this in your Umbraco BaseTree subclass in a similar manner to Robert (looping over and creating XmlTreeNodes etc).

Comment: Thank you very much, this has really helped me get past the bit I was stuck on and cleared a few things up in my mind.